# Trying to display servers with a list of services and wither they are running or not

Tags: powershell

Basically each day I get a report of servers with a list of services not running. the report will read like ServerName, Services. I want to pull this report in from a csv file and then run the script to see the status of each service listed for the server.

So, If I get a report like Server1, ADobe not running
                           Server1, SQL not running
                           Server2, SQL not running

I am most of the way there but, the loops are running get-service on servers that don't have the service listed. I am trying to find a way to remove the service from the array after each iteration of the loop but, I am finding it hard to do with powershell. There also might just be a better way of doing it all together.

What I have so far is

```
$servers = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\zada\Documents\New Text Document.csv' | % {$_.Servername}
$services = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\zada\Documents\New Text Document.csv' | % {$_.Servicename}

foreach ($server in $servers) {
    Write-Host ***************** getting services list for $server *******************
    foreach ($service in $services)   {
        Get-Service -ComputerName $server -Name $services | Format-Table -Property Status, Name, DisplayName -AutoSize

    }

}
```

The problem is it runs through each server as many times as there are services listed and not all the servers have the same services. I toyed around with running running $service.remove($services) but, that didn't get me anywhere.

Below is an example of how the csv file looks.

```
Servername  Servicename
server1 SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS)
server1 WSUS
server2 Sophos System Protection Service
server3 WindowsRM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance you are over complicating this.

> The problem is it runs through each server as many times as there are services listed and not all the servers have the same services.

This is because of how you built your loop structure of course. Let `Import-CSV` do its job and then iterate over each row individually.

```
Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\zada\Documents\New Text Document.csv' | Foreach-Object{
    Get-Service -ComputerName $_.ServerName -Name $_.ServiceName 
} | select MachineName, Status, Name, DisplayName
```

However that would be considered inefficient since you are querying the same server several times needlessly. What we should do is group all the servers together and then query them once. ...

```
Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\zada\Documents\New Text Document.csv' | Group-Object ServerName | ForEach-Object{
    # The name of the group we are in is the ServerName
    $serverName = $_.Name
    # Create an array of all services we are checking on this host
    $services = $_.Group.ServiceName

    Get-Service -ComputerName $serverName -Name $services
} | select MachineName, Status, Name, DisplayName
```

So we group all of the rows with the same server name and query for all services in the CSV associated to that server in one cmdlet call.

Comment: Oh, wow yeah I totally was. I tried adding Computername also to the select portion but, it spits out blank.

Comment: Try 'MachineName'

Comment: Wow man thats such an elegant way of doing this. Thanks so much I have a lot to learn still.

Comment: @zacharyadams As do well all.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example where you don't need to know the services beforehand:

```
$Services = Get-Service -ComputerName $Servers |
              Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'stopped' } |
              ForEach-Object { <# ... #> }
```

But this will put all the stopped services into an array, not particular to which server they were stopped on.  I'm not entirely certain of what you want to accomplish without an example dataset.

---

Update based on feedback:

```
$CSV = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\zada\Documents\New Text Document.csv'

[HashTable]$Services = @{}

For ($i = 0; $i -lt $CSV.Count; $i++)
{
    $Services[$CSV[$i].Servers] += ,$CSV[$i].ServiceName
}
```

This will generate your hashtable so you can do what you want:

```
ForEach ($Server in $Services.Keys) {
    Write-Host "Getting services for $Server"
    Get-Service -ComputerName $Server -Include $Services.$Server |
      Format-Table -Property Status,Name,DisplayName -Autosize
}
```

Comment: I don't care about all the stopped services. Only specific ones I have monitoring on.

Comment: Here is an example 

    Servername Servicename
    server1 SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS)
    server2 Sophos System Protection Service

Comment: Then I suggest using `Get-Service -Include @('name1','name2','etc')`

Comment: the server list and services list is always changing though. Having hard code the list on the script would be time consuming.

Comment: Are the services specified in the CSV?  You can assign them into an array to correspond with the server and pass the array to the `-Include` parameter.

Comment: Basically I get the report and copy and paste the values into a CSV. I added some more to the post to showcase how it could look.

Comment: Is the `servicename` field comma separated based on service name (not only separated by spaces for example)? Is that full service name the actual name of the service?

Comment: Correct they are comma seperated and yes it's the actual name of the service. If I do $service with a random server it works fine.

Comment: @zacharyadams I would suggest converting the `PSCustomObject` that `Import-CSV` gives you into a `[HashTable]` of all the services that relate to a server and then the looping becomes very easy.  Working on updating my answer.

Comment: @zacharyadams check the update.  All it relies on is your CSV as-is and that the service name matches the property status name exactly (can be modified to use wildcards)